# How to find if a key exists in MongoDb document?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following mongodb document

```
{

"user_100":{
    "name": "Scott" ,
    "uniqueDetails":{
    "mobile":"9999999999",
    "email": "scott@abc.com",
    }
},
"user_101":{
    "name": "Smith",
    "uniqueDetails":{
    "mobile":"9999999998",
    "email": "smith@abc.com"
    }
}
}
```

Now, when a new user signs up, I would like to check if a given mobile number/email already exists. Is there any solution for this with **Java MongoDB API**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a query and search in the collection for the tags that you want:

For example:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("email", email_to_seach);

DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);

try {
   while(cursor.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(cursor.next());
   }
} finally {
   cursor.close();
}
```

Also, you can look for only the first document that has the email or mobile phone that you want, with:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("email", email_to_seach);
DBObject myDoc = coll.findOne(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the com.mongodb.QueryBuilder class to build a query:

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("mobile").is(mobileNumberToSearch)
    .or(QueryBuilder.start("email").is(emailToSearch).get()).get();

DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find(query);
if(dbCursor.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("mobile number or email already exists");
}
```